# Setting httpc proxy in iex (Phoenix project)

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

My query to Wolfram Alpha fails when using iex behind a proxy.
I tried setting the proxy using

```
iex(1)> :httpc.set_options({:proxy, {"proxy.mycompany.org", 1234}})
```

but this is giving a CaseClauseError error. How do I set options within iex for this Erlang library?
Thank you.

Background: I am going through the book "Programming Phoenix"

Comment: Try single quotes and wrapping the whole thing in a list: `[{:proxy, {'proxy.mycompany.org', 1234}}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:

1. `set_options` accepts a list of options, not one option.
2. The hostname must be an Erlang string, which is called a charlist in Elixir, and is created using single quotes in Elixir.
3. That option requires a tuple `{Proxy, NoProxy}` where `NoProxy` is a list of `NoProxyDesc` options. You might want to read the documentation for that; I'm using an empty list below.

You can also use the keyword list syntax to make this slightly shorter:

```
iex(1)> :httpc.set_options([{:proxy, {{'proxy.mycompany.org', 1234}, []}}])
:ok
```

---

You can also use the keyword list syntax to make this slightly shorter:

```
iex(2)> :httpc.set_options([proxy: {{'proxy.mycompany.org', 1234}, []}])
:ok
```